# Mypy stub files and VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, mypy

I have problems with stub files in vs code. I use Pylance but I don't get IntelliSense when the stub files are not in the same folder as their implementation, even if the subfolder corresponds to the "python.analysis.stubPath" setting.
I don't like to put all the stub files in the same folder as their implementation because I find it kind of ugly, so when reading the docs of Pylance, it should work if I put them in a subfolder named typings (default stubPath), but it doesn't, here is a minimal example:
With the current file structure:

```
test/
  foo/
    typings/
      foo.pyi
    foo.py
  test.py
```

**foo/foo.py**

```py
Foo = type("Foo", (), { x: 1, y: 2 })
```

**foo/typings/foo.pyi**

```py
class Foo:
  x: int
  y: int
```

**test.py**

```py
from foo.foo import Foo # Here IntelliSense gives me def Foo() -> object, but it should give me class Foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `foo` as a workspace, it seems that ***typings*** can only exist in the root directory, and cannot go deep into the directory.

[image]

In addition, there is a following setting, you can try to modify the path to see if it works.

```json
    // Path to directory containing custom type stub files.
    "python.analysis.stubPath": "typings",
```